# SQL dates returns 12/20/18 when it should be 12/20/17

Tags: sql, date, dateadd, datepart

Any help would be appreciated. it works for 2/10/18, 3/10/18 but not 4/10/18 
This is to get a date range for a report that runs every month on the 10th for all accounts that are 75 day past due and not reported on last month report

```
DECLARE @TODAYS_DT DATE = '4/10/2018'

DECLARE @START_DT CHAR(10)
DECLARE @END_DT   CHAR(10)

SELECT  
    @START_DT = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MM, DATEADD(MM, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -75, '4/10/2018')))) + '/20/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -75, '4/10/2018')))

SELECT  
    @END_DT = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MM, DATEADD(DAY, -75, '4/10/2018'))) + '/20/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -75, '4/10/2018')))

SELECT  
    @START_DT, @END_DT
```

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you are *trying* to do.  Broken code doesn't really work so well for that purpose.

Comment: Which result represents your problem? What date do you expect instead? Why do you expect that? What locale is your session using (i.e. is 4/10/2018 meant to be 4 October, or 10 April)? But mostly, as Gordon asks, what exactly are you trying to do? Because there may well be an easier way than the textual manipulation of strings representing dates...

Comment: You post a question with a broken code, without description.  How you do expect us to understand what you want to accomplished????  Learn how to ask question!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you think it should be 2017? 4/10/2018 minus 75 days is 1/24/2018.

Comment: And running your code as-is gives `@START_DT = '12/21/2018'`, `@END_DT = '1/20/2018'`. What are you trying to do with these dates? As Matt said, there may be an easier way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: it should return 12/21/2017  if you run for 3/10/2018 it returns 12/20/17

Answer (score 0):

You need to go further back in time to get to 2017.  Try subtracting 100 instead of 75.

```
DECLARE @TODAYS_DT DATE = '4/10/2018'

DECLARE @START_DT CHAR(10)
DECLARE @END_DT   CHAR(10)

SELECT  
    @START_DT = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MM, DATEADD(MM, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -100, '4/10/2018')))) + '/21/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -100, '4/10/2018')))

SELECT  
    @END_DT = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MM, DATEADD(DAY, -100, '4/10/2018'))) + '/20/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -100, '4/10/2018')))

SELECT  
    @START_DT, @END_DT
```

Comment: This is to get a date range for a report that runs every month on the 10th  for all accounts that are 75 day past due and not reported on last month report

Comment: So why do you think it should go back to 2017 then?

Comment: Because the 3/10/18 returned 12/20/18 end date and the 4/10/2018 so expected result 12/20/2017 start date but returns 12/20/2018